# mysql python hangup debugging

Tags: python, mysql, debugging

My program seems to not be terminating... As I am relatively new to python I would suspect I made a common mistake that I do not see yet. Even recently in Java I have resolved simple problems like this by closing a file...

**NOTE:** `rt_table` has about 250,000 rows. Before this python program I had written an equivalent Java program and it did not take long to execute.

```
def create_AMatrix():
    """Create the adjacency table of the retweet network from rt_table to create an adjacency matrix"""
    con = mdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="twitter")    
    cur = con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    #get vertex set of users in retweet network
    cur.execute("select user_id from users")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    vSet = list()
    for uID in rows:
        vSet.append(uID)

    #populate adjacency table
    cur.execute("select * from rt_table")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        sourceUserID = row["source_user_id"]
        sourceUserName = row["source_user_name"]
        rtUserID = row["rt_user_id"]
        rtUserName = row["rt_user_name"]
        try:
            curRow = vSet.index(sourceUserID)
            curCol = vSet.index(rtUserID)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        cur.execute("select COUNT(*) from adjacency where r = %s and c = %s", (curRow, curCol))
        if cur.fetchone()['COUNT(*)'] == 0:
            try:
                cur.execute("insert into adjacency (r, c, val, source_user_id, source_user_name, rt_user_id, rt_user_name) values (%d, %d, %d, %d, %s, %d, %s"), (curRow, curCol, 1, sourceUserID, sourceUserName, rtUserID, rtUserName)
                con.commit()
            except:
                con.rollback()
        else:
            try:
                cur.execute("update adjacency set val = val+1 where r = %d and c = %d"), (curRow, curCol)
                con.commit()
            except:
                con.rollback()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```

1. Where is my error?
2. What can I do to find out what my code is doing? Specifically, can I ask what line of code the program is executing?

All help is greatly appreciated, and feel free to make suggestions to make my code more pythonic!

Comment: Did I get you right? You are looking for a debugger? http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Comment: I am also looking for where my error is... I still may not find it even with a debugger

Comment: I don't like python because it depends on whitespace. It's a pain to fix a bug where you have a tab and in the next line you have 4 spaces. I'm sorry that I can't help you more.

Comment: I am running this as a script. There is no "compiler" error (I know the language is interpreted but I am not familiar with how a script is  executed)

Comment: I'd start by putting some print statements in there printing out elapsed time, to see where it's getting hung up.

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem I can see is this snippet:

```
try:
    curRow = vSet.index(sourceUserID)
    curCol = vSet.index(rtUserID)
except ValueError:
    continue
```

The `list.index()` function searches the list in O(N) time. You're also calling it O(N) times, so your overall efficiency is O(N^2). With N = 250,000, that's a pretty huge inefficiency. I don't see any obvious errors in your code, so I'd guess that the reason it's not returning is because it would take hours to complete, and you're not waiting that long.

One thing you could try is replacing vSet with a dict. From looking at your code, it looks like the only thing you use vSet for is looking up the index of various user IDs, so try replacing this:

```
vSet = list()
for uID in rows:
    vSet.append(uID)
```

with this:

```
vSet = dict()
for index, row in enumerate(rows):
    vSet[row['user_id']] = index
```

Looking things up in a dict is an O(1) operation, so this should get you to O(N) total runtime.

Also, notice how instead of putting `uID` into the lookup dict (which would have put in a row), I just put the actual `user_id` value -- because later on, you're looking up user IDs, not rows. I haven't run your code to test it, but I suspect if it had run to completion, you would have found you had zero output rows, because ints don't compare equal to DB cursor rows and so your code to set `curRow` and `curCol` would never have succeeded.

Oh, and of course you'll need to change your `curRow` and `curCol` snippet to:

```
try:
    curRow = vSet[sourceUserID]
    curCol = vSet[rtUserID]
except IndexError:
    continue
```

Try making those changes, and see if that makes your code work better.

Also, the advice to sprinkle `print` statements around in your code is a good one. I usually try that first before reaching for a debugger, and most of the time that's enough to clue me in on what the code is doing, and I don't need to pull out the big guns of a debugger. If you do want a Python debugger, though, Google for `pdb` and read up on how to use it. You can use it from the command line, or integrate it into whatever IDE you're using, depending on how you prefer to work.